# How to get pandas dataframe when select only one column? In R there is drop = False for that

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to get pandas dataframe when select only one column? In R there is `drop = False` for that.

We can use `pd.DataFrame(df['breakfast'])` or `df[['breakfast']]`, but do we have smth like `drop = False` as it in R?

PS: press `F` for breakfast)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like `index=df.index`.

The question is a bit broad

Comment: No, what he mean is getting single column as data frame https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html